# which tokens/codes/ids actually need to be exchanged for google oauth

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-python-client

i'm trying to follow the example code [on google's website here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow), but it seems a little broken - the javascript references getting a list of people from the server, but in the server-side code there's no reference to calling those functions of the api, it just returns an HTTP status code and a text status, so i'm wondering if there's a step missing and i'm exchanging the wrong code at the wrong time.

my current flow is

1. login button button clicked, magic happens, my callback gets passed an object with a whole bunch of properties in it
2. I take the `code` property from that object, and post it back to my server in an ajax request
3. on my server, i run the following python, where `auth_code_from_js` is the data of my post request:

   `oauth_flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', scope='')`
   `credentials = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(auth_code_from_js)`
4. python throws a FlowExchangeError with the message `invalid request` and no other useful information

am i missing a step?  is that initial 'code' property what i'm supposed to be passing in to the 'step2_exchange' method?